# Looking for proof: bases without any 'Rotate-Left-Double numbers' is the same sequence as A056469

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, continued-fractions, number-systems

I'm very active on the [codegolf stackexchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), where the goal of [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) is to complete a certain task/challenge in as few bytes as possible. Although the challenge isn't live yet, someone [proposed this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18736/52210), which I will also partially quote here:

> ## Task
>
> A Rotate-Left-Double number in base $n$ is a number $m$, when its base-$n$ digits are rotated left once, equals $2m$.
>
> One example in base $7$ is the number $480=1254_7$. When rotated left once, the value becomes $2541_7=960$.
>
> Given the base $n\geq2$, determine if there exists a Rotate-Left-Double number in base $n$.
>
> You can use your language's convention to represent truthy/falsy, or use two distinct values for truthy and falsy respectively.

The challenge proposer also posted [a reference implementation in Python](https://tio.run/##bVFdb4IwFH3nV5xkWQSsRvBlqfGXNH2ga9VmeGEIW/317BbJcMlemvbm3PPV9t5fGirH0boT@sZUN5eSMJlMEHCE0gm@L752IEnC8sT6r2tjJ8wBYVu1rSOb2ixB5/qhIwQl5abQSSQ8dc31mXKGdM4O7y6tq6uxFYK4S4TcrO8CJLDLkuTUdDDwjKzo7NJSFG9xve089TAiwefgBhf9qaAR0WFBF6yl4U/M8IoSrr65f3GlMKLMfgNOlCwCYt7psW2bNmU7iGR/oiBn4uPxaagKqbEGKVloAQ47m6UDTOeqDyZ5mSd8jU784mTqhoWZk9XXUF4/3iFO5l9ZtNh4lscjgtgalZM6@4kbKrYv5wTz91A5p6jqOg1qs2c4qyu10/leQBleyfdPDU3bmVx6ZkOxyOjzEWNFTX/xdF6N4w8).

When I was preparing a solution for when this challenge would go live, I noticed that all falsey test cases within the range $n=[2,500]$ seem to be forming the OEIS sequence [A056469](http://oeis.org/A056469): *number of elements in the continued fraction for $\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{1}{2})^{2^k}$*, which could be simplified to $a(n)=\left\lfloor2^{n-1}+2\right\rfloor$. Here a copy of the first 25 numbers in that sequence as reference:

```
2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 18, 34, 66, 130, 258, 514, 1026, 2050, 4098, 8194, 16386, 32770, 65538, 131074, 262146, 524290, 1048578, 2097154, 4194306, 8388610
```

So now I have two questions:

1. Is my assumption correct, or is it simply a coincidence that the falsey test cases in the range $n=[2,500]$ are all powers of 2 after decreasing by 2?
2. If my assumption is indeed correct, how can this be proven in relation to the 'Rotate-Left-Double numbers' for the given base $n$?

Comment: Sorry.  I've been posting and deleting comments as I've gotten myself confused.  (I have trouble distinguishing right and left.)  My earlier comment was correct.  Suppose we have a $(d+1)$-digit example in base $n$: $m=xn^d+y$ where $0\leq x<n$ and $0<y<n^d$.  Rotating $m$ left gives $ny+x$, so the condition is $$(2n^d-1)x=(n-2)y$$  When $n=3$ this gives $(2\cdot3^d-1)x=y<3^d$ which is impossible unless $x=y=0$ which is excluded.  How can there be an example with $n=3$?  Where is my error?

Comment: @saulspatz I think you've flipped truthy/falsey. The sequence I posted applies to the **falsey** test cases, so the bases for which there there aren't any 'Rotate-Left-Double numbers' available. For all other bases (thus `[5,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,...]`) there are. So if you've found prove that for \$n=3\$ there aren't any possible solutions, this is correct.

Comment: Off-topic, but regarding having trouble distinguishing right/left: the same user actually has [a different challenge regarding 'Rotate-Right-Double numbers'](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18735/52210). Unlike the 'Rotate-Left-Double numbers', these apparently always have a solution, for which the smallest number for each base \$n\$ can be found in the OEIS sequence [A087502](http://oeis.org/A087502). Not really useful for my question, but figured I'd mention it anyway for those interested.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the question carefully, thanks.  But now I have another question.  If $01_2$ is rotated left, we get $10_2$ so  $n=2$ isn't a falsey case, though it's listed in your sequence.  Do you to mean to exclude that when you say it's a power of $2$ after decreasing by $2$?  This doesn't seem very clear.

Comment: @saulspatz Hmm, good point. I will ask that challenge giver why $n=2$ is falsey. Although I assume it's because of that leading 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m$ is a $(d+1)$-digit Rotate-Left-Double number in base in base $n$ then $$m=xn^d+y\tag1$$ where $d\geq1,\ 0<x<n,\ 0\leq y<n^d.$  (I have adopted the rule that the number can't start with $0$.)  Rotating $m$ gives $ny+x$ so we have $2xn^d+2y=ny+x$ or $$(n-2)y=(2n^d-1)x\tag2$$ If $n=2^k+2$ then $(2)$ gives $(n-2)|x$ since $2n^s-1$ is odd.  But then $y\geq 2n^d-1$ which contradicts $y<n^d$.

To show that these are the only falsey numbers, let $p$ be an odd prime dividing $n-2$.  (Such a $p$ exists because $n-2$ is not a power of $2$.)  In $(2)$ we can take $x=\frac{n-2}p<n$ and we have to we have to show that there exist an exponent $d>0$ and $0\leq y<n^d$ such that $$py = 2n^d-1$$ If we can find a $d$ such that $p|(2n^d-1)$, we are done, for we can take $y = \frac{2n^d-1}p<n^d.$

By assumption, $n-2\equiv0\pmod{p}$ so $n\equiv 2\pmod p.$  Therefore, $$2n^d\equiv1\iff 2\cdot2^d\equiv1 \iff 2^{d+1}\equiv 1\pmod p,$$ and by Fermat's little theorem, we can take $d=p-2$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My math skills are pretty bad, so I have two small questions: 1. what does the $|$ signify in $(n-2)|x$ and $j|2n^d-1$? 2. I'm a bit confused about the "_If $n=2^k+2$ then $(2)$ gives $(n−2)|x$ since $2n^s−1$ is odd._" I get the second part about it being odd, but I'm not sure how it went from $n=2^k+2$ in $(2)$ to $(n−2)|x$. It's probably obvious when I see some sub-steps, but feel free to do it here in the comments to not clutter the answer if you want. These two questions of mine are mostly clarifications for me personally. The proof as an entirety is clear, thanks!

Comment: @Kevin Sure. $|$ means "divides" or "is a divisor of".  If $n=2^k+2$ then $n-2=2^k$.  Now $2^k$ divides the left-hand side of $(2)$, so it must divide the right-hand side.  $2^k$ has no factors in common with an odd number, so it must divide $x$.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm glad you asked the question.  It made me look at the proof again, and I found a hole!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I fixed it.  It's simpler as well as being correct (I trust.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. One new question if you don't mind: how did we get from $2^{d+1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ to $d=p-2$ with [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)? The theorem seems to state $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ or $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$. Using this second one, we know $a^{p-1}-1\equiv 0\pmod p$, so the $2^{d+1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ can become $2^d-1\equiv 0\pmod p$ and then $2^d\equiv p-1\pmod p$ (correct me if I'm wrong, which is highly likely). But how does $2^d\equiv p-1\pmod p$ then become $d=p-2$ instead of $d=\log_2(p-1)$?

Comment: If we set $d=p-2$ then $2^{d+1}=2^{p-2+1}=2^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ by little Fermat.

Comment: Ah, of course. Can't believe I looked past something that now seems so obvious. Thanks again for the proof! PS: The challenge went live and I posted [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202945/52210), with your proof and a link to here to credit you of course.

Comment: Thank you.  Glad to help.